# Get the Real FilePath from a shared video file

Tags: android, path, send

good morning everyone

I have this code in my app, it is to receive a file from another application through the share button. And here, no problem.

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String action = intent.getAction();
String type = intent.getType();
if (Intent.ACTION_SEND.equals(action) && type != null) {
    if (type.startsWith("video/")) {
        Uri imageUri = intent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM);
        String path = imageUri.getPath();
        // /item/4567592  --> whatsapp
        // /media/telegram/telegram docuemnts/name.mp4 --> telegram
        // no more apps tested
    }
}
```

The question is that I want the absolute absolute path of the file, yes, I do not want to use a File, or anything else, I want the actual path of the file on the device.

I have tried 1000 things, also the solutions with the Cursor, but they return null, or other puzzling errors.

I tried to save the file in the internal memory or in the cache of the app, but I did not get it either.

Suggestions?
Thank you!

Comment: `String path = imageUri.getPath();`. Replace by `String path = imageUri.toString();` And relalise that you got a nice content scheme.

Comment: `"I want the actual path of the file on the device."` you cannot get that path - if you just need the "human-friendly name" of that `Uri` use `ContentResolver#query()` method, if you need its content use `ContentResolver#openInputStream()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want the absolute absolute path of the file.

You should not want that. There is no reason for it as long as you do not have to supply the 'path' to an external library.

Just open an `InputStream`. Read from the stream and save to file.

```
InputStream is = getContentResolver().openInputStream(imageUri);
```

You can use the input stream as if it was the file input stream.

Comment: Well, to tell the truth, I need to pass it to another library. To this one in particular http://writingminds.github.io/ffmpeg-android-java/

Comment: @user1814720: Then use the `InputStream` to make a copy of the content in some file that you control, then pass the file to the library. If the `Uri` scheme *happens* to be `file`, you're welcome to call `getPath()` and use that, but much of the time, the scheme will be `content`.